# error: AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'newPage' when doing youtube webscraping

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, data-science, python-requests-html

I'm trying to do a webscraping on youtube to get the information from a video, however it is giving an error and it seems that it is in the renders () of requests_html, code below:

```
from requests_html import AsyncHTMLSession
import pyppdf.patch_pyppeteer
import pyppeteer

import asyncio
if asyncio.get_event_loop().is_running(): # Only patch if needed (i.e. running in Notebook, Spyder, etc)
    import nest_asyncio
    nest_asyncio.apply()
    
url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3vY2L0ikq8w"

session = AsyncHTMLSession()
# inserindo a query e o numero da pagina na url
print(url)
# enviado requisição para o youtube
response = await session.get(url)
# executando Java-script
await response.html.render(sleep=1)
# renomear o arquivo
link_name = re.search('v=(.*)', link).group(1)
# Salvando arquivo HTML na pasta dados_brutos
with open("./dados_brutos/videos/video_{}.html".format(link_name), 'w+', encoding='utf8') as output:
    output.write(response.html.html)
    
time.sleep(2)
```

**error description**

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in async-def-wrapper()
> 19 # renomear o arquivo
> 20 link_name = re.search('v=(.*)', link).group(1)
> ---> 21 # Salvando arquivo HTML na pasta dados_brutos
> 22 with open("./dados_brutos/videos/video_{}.html".format(link_name), 'w+',
> encoding='utf8') as output:
> 23     output.write(response.html.html)
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests_html.py
> in render(self, retries, script, wait, scrolldown, sleep, reload,
> timeout, keep_page)
> 596                 try:
> 597
> --> 598                     content, result, page = self.session.loop.run_until_complete(self._async_render(url=self.url,
> script=script, sleep=sleep, wait=wait, content=self.html,
> reload=reload, scrolldown=scrolldown, timeout=timeout,
> keep_page=keep_page))
> 599                 except TypeError:
> 600                     pass
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nest_asyncio.py
> in run_until_complete(self, future)
> 93                 raise RuntimeError(
> 94                     'Event loop stopped before Future completed.')
> ---> 95             return f.result()
> 96         finally:
> 97             events._set_running_loop(old_running_loop)
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\futures.py in
> result(self)
> 176         self.__log_traceback = False
> 177         if self._exception is not None:
> --> 178             raise self._exception
> 179         return self._result
> 180
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py in
> __step(***failed resolving arguments***)
> 221                 # We use the `send` method directly, because coroutines
> 222                 # don't have `__iter__` and `__next__` methods.
> --> 223                 result = coro.send(None)
> 224             else:
> 225                 result = coro.throw(exc)
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests_html.py
> in _async_render(self, url, script, scrolldown, sleep, wait, reload,
> content, timeout, keep_page)
> 503         """ Handle page creation and js rendering. Internal use for render/arender methods. """
> 504         try:
> --> 505             page = await self.browser.newPage()
> 506
> 507             # Wait before rendering the page, to prevent timeouts.
>
> AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'newPage'

help me run this code

Answer (score 0):

change your render with arender and session with asession

```
response = await asession.get(url)
# executando Java-script
await response.html.arender(sleep=1)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).